# How to toggle image show/hide using JS/JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
  <script src="js/yahoo.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <button id=jad>jad</button>
  <button id= hecho>hecho</button>
  <button id=mewto>mewto</button>
  <div>
    <img id="obj-2" src="Jew.png" alt="" width="800" height="400" />
  </div>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#jad").click(function(){
    $("#jad").attr("src") == "jad.png";
  });
});
```

Trying to figure out the best way to show/hide an image on click.
Using jquery, but curious how things would change w just javascript.

Comment: I just noticed you are posting questions where the answer have been easily found on any tutorial site if you only took the time to check it out. We are here to help, though no effort of your own have been made to make a plain javascript conversion, nor is your jQuery close to what's on their pages. I vote to close both your questions because of that. At this question I also decided to delete my answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no real effort have been made to solve what's asked for

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery:

```
$('#obj-2').css('display', 'none'); //To hide it
$('#obj-2').css('display', 'block'); //To show it
```

With plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById('obj-2').style.display = "none"; //To hide it
document.getElementById('obj-2').style.display = "block"; //To show it
```

Answer (score -2):

You button IDs should be in quotes too.

```
<button id="jad">jad</button>
<button id= "hecho">hecho</button>
<button id="mewto">mewto</button>
```